# Couldn't store audio as MP3 file using soundfile

Tags: python, librosa, soundfile

My intention is to process MP3 file using **Librosa** library (normalize volume, trim silences, etc). However, as Librosa doesn't support MP3 format I use **audioread** library to load audio; however, I could not find the function in audioread that writes back the file, for that purpose I have loaded soundfile and saved processed file into WAV. Unfortunately, I am able to save only one channel (MONO) not Stereo.
Kindly advise, what library can I use to load and write MP3 file and process it using Librosa? or how can I write both channels into WAV or MP3 using soundfile?

```
import audioread, librosa
import soundfile as sf

filename="../sounds/music.mp3"

audio_file = audioread.audio_open(filename)
audio, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr= 44100)
clip = librosa.effects.trim(audio, top_db= 10)
sf.write('../sounds/output/out.wav', clip[0], sr, 'PCM_24')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundfile supports multichannel saving just fine. However, Librosa works with audio arrays where the dimensions are: (N_channels, N_samples). Soundfile on the other hand works with: (N_samples, N_channels). You can use numpy to transpose from one format to the other:

```
sf.write('../sounds/output/out.wav', np.transpose(clip), sr, 'PCM_24')
```